# Using a tab of ints returned from method in main

Tags: java, tabs, return, program-entry-point

I have a problem with my code-this metod returns a tab of ints:

```
int[] czynnikiPierwsze(int n){
    dzielniki=new int[20];
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(n%tab[i]==0){
            dzielniki[j]=tab[i];
            n=n/tab[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    return dzielniki;
}
```

There are for example {2,2,3,8,0,0,0,0,0} in this tab(dzielniki).
How can i use this tab in main and print those numbers ?
I created new object and used that method:

```
RozkladLiczby a=new RozkladLiczby(100);
    System.out.println(a.czynnikiPierwsze(69));
```

And i get werid output: [I@1693b52b - Probably because i want to print the whole tab at once, how can i print it property ?

Comment: By "tab" do you mean "array"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of `int`s is an object too, but that "class" doesn't override the [`toString` method from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), which is responsible for the "weird output" you see:

> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Print the array using [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)) instead.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.czynnikiPierwsze(69)));
```

Comment: Another question, if I would like to print this tab step by step for example: 2 next 2 in next move 3 etc or i would like to print it like: 2*2*3 how can I do that?